# Can we create format file from bcp command line as a different field terminator for each field?

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcp

We are using non-XML format file to import data into Sql Server database through bcp utility. We have used comma(,) as a field separator in the bcp.

Now we are getting issue when user provides comma(,) between the string field like name. Field get terminates by comma(,) and rest of the words goes in to the next field. We can not change the separator at this point of time. So we are looking for some other solutions.

We found a way that users will enclose all the string values columns in double quotes. we can scan first ten rows of the file and see if there is a double quote(“) in the line. If a double quote is found we have to update the format file so that doubles quotes get treated as text qualifiers and everything with in double quotes are treated as a column value.

So my question is can we code this programmatically if we find double quotes we can make field separator as ",\"" and then for the next record the terminator will be "\"," and if there will be no double quote we can keep our terminator as ",".

Or simply I want to ask how can we create different field terminator for different fields ? I went through some goggling and found in the bcp command line we have only -t that creates the field terminator and this will keep the same for all the fields.